# Generic object comparison diff routine

Tags: c#, generics, diff

The question stems from  database tables comparison. Let's say we put left row in the instance Left and the right one into instance Right of the same type. And we'got many tables and respective types.

How to implement more or less generic routine resulting in a collection of diffs e.g.
propertyName , leftValue , rightValue for each such a pair of instances of the same type.
Apart from generic algorithm of comparison since leftValue and rightValue can be anything ( pair of strings or int or DateTime or Guid ) is not obvious how to combine all that in one collection.

**EDIT:**

```
class OneOfManyTypesBasedOnTableRow 
{
   Guid uid,
   int  anotherId,
   string text1,
   string text2,
   DateTime date1, 
   DateTime date2 
}
class AnotherOfManyTypesBasedOnTableRow 
{
   Guid uid,
   int  anotherId,
   string text3,
   string text4,
   DateTime date3, 
   DateTime date4 
}

//For type 1
OneOfManyTypesBasedOnTableRow  Left =  new Something().GetLeft() ;
OneOfManyTypesBasedOnTableRow  Right =  new Something().GetRight() ;
DiffCollection1 diff1 = comparer.GetDiffForOneOfManyTypesBasedOnTableRow ( Left , Right ) ;   

//For type 2

AnotherOfManyTypesBasedOnTableRow  Left =  new SomethingElse().GetLeft() ;
AnotherOfManyTypesBasedOnTableRow  Right =  new SomethingElse().GetRight() ;
DiffCollection2 diff2 = comparer.GetDiffForAnotherOfManyTypesBasedOnTableRow ( Left , Right ) ;
```

My problem is that I don't know how to avoid repetition of that quite similar code for each type. It might be ok for objects population . But in diff  methods  I have to code

```
if Left.Text1.Equals ( Right.Text1 )
```

and so on in one method

```
if Left.Text3.Equals ( Right.Text3 )
```

and so on in other method

Comment: Can you put some psuedo code up describing this.

Comment: One thing I have done is to make a method which returns a list of the values (in order) that are "important". Then I use that list (not the actual) object to compare Equality and generate a Hash. This is similar to a slightly more automated process as mentioned in Mathew's answer but places the "import field" selection in the hands of the object (attributes could also be used I guess). This can be done really easily across a number of objects with an interface and static helper or extension method -- should be less than ~8 lines of code per class.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want but this method can do a shallow comparison on two objects matching properties and comparing them to see if they are equal.

```
private static bool DoObjectsMatch(object object1, object object2)
{
    var props1 = object1.GetType()
                    .GetProperties()
                    .ToDictionary<PropertyInfo,string,object>(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(object1, null));
    var props2 = object2.GetType()
                    .GetProperties()
                    .ToDictionary<PropertyInfo,string,object>(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(object2, null));
    var query = from prop1 in props1
                join prop2 in props2 on prop1.Key equals prop2.Key
                select prop1.Value == null ? prop2.Value == null : prop1.Value.Equals(prop2.Value);

    return query.Count(x => x) == Math.Max(props1.Count(), props2.Count());
}
```

Using this method you can compare two objects based one matching property names.  For example:

```
class Thing 
{
   public int  Id {get;set;}
   public string Text{get;set;}
}

void Main()
{
    var t1 = new Thing{ Id = 3, Text = "hi" };
    var t2 = new Thing{ Id = 3, Text = "hi" };
    var t3 = new Thing{ Id = 4, Text = "bye" };

    Console.WriteLine(DoObjectsMatch(t1,t2)); // True
    Console.WriteLine(DoObjectsMatch(t2,t3)); // False
}
```

Comment: I prefer a slightly more verbose "manual" approach with an explicit selection of "important values", but nice general answer.

Answer (score 1):

I created a library to do just this and provide some additional metadata.  Unfortunately it relies on MVC `ModelMetadata` and `DataAnnotations` to provide a "readable version" of the diff for non technical users.   So it would use your `DisplayName` for a property instead of its actual property name.

But it does provide the ability to get a programmatic representation of the diff for you own uses instead of using the "Readable" extensions.

https://github.com/paultyng/ObjectDiff

Given objects like:

```
var before = new 
{ 
    Property1 = "", 
    MultilineText = "abc\ndef\nghi", 
    ChildObject = new { ChildProperty = 7 }, 
    List = new string[] { "a", "b" } 
};

var after = new 
{ 
    Property1 = (string)null, 
    MultilineText = "123\n456", 
    NotPreviouslyExisting = "abc", 
    ChildObject = new { ChildProperty = 6 }, 
    List = new string[] { "b", "c" } 
};
```

The readable diff extensions output something like:

```
ChildObject - ChildProperty: '6', was '7'
List - [2, added]: 'c', was not present
List - [removed]: No value present, was 'a'
MultilineText: 
-----
123
456
-----
was 
-----
abc
def
ghi
-----
NotPreviouslyExisting: 'abc', was not present
```

But the programmatic diff would give you information about every property and list item and you could do with that what you will.

I plan to split out the MVC requirement in the future, its all open sourced, so you can hack on it as you will.  It may be a good place to start if not an exact fit for your needs.